# How to know the number of remaining input items in multiprocessing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading, multiprocessing

I am using `multiprocessing.Pool` to parallelize the task. Consider an example code below,

```
rangeval = range(1000)
pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
pool.map(f, iterable=rangeval)
```

Here, I want to be able to print, `len(rangeval)` for each function `f` execution. I tried to do it with a counter to know when the each task is done and what is the number of the task. But the print happens without sorting, so there is no way to know how many of `rangeval` items left or done. I am doing the following.

```
import multiprocessing

counter = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
def f(x):
    global counter
    counter.value += 1
    print("Done with task: ", counter.value)
    return x


if __name__ == '__main__':
    rangeval = range(1000)
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    pool.map(f, iterable=rangeval)
```

It prints,

```
Done with task: Done with task:  Done with task: 30
 163Done with task: 
 31
Done with task:  Done with task: 164
```

But I want to be able to say the length of `rangeval` so that I can get how many items are left in the input. Or if this counter value printing happens in a sorted way without introducing sleep or any extra computation, that would be fine too.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: You might want (or need) to implement your own producer/consumer model (what pooling does for you) so you can examine the size of the work queue directly.

Comment: maybe you should create other variable liek `counter` but with value `len(rangeval)` and every process will run `variable.value -= 1` before `return`  and this way you will know how many processes are still running.

Comment: you should print it as single string `print( f"Done with task: {counter.value}\n", end='')` and you will have task number in the same line as `Done with task:`

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:**

It seems it works for `Linux` which uses method `fork` to create processes and it shares some elements between processes - but `Windows` uses method `spawn` (and it doesn't have `fork`) and it may need totally different solution. Maybe it will need to send data to processes as argument, or use `Queue` to communicate with main processes which will have to change `running`. I don't use `Windows` so I can't test it.

---

I would create variable with `len(rangeval)`

```
running = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)

running.value = len(rangeval)
```

and every function should decrease it before `return`

To get correct value it may need also `Lock`

```
    with lock:    
        running.value -= 1

if __name__ == '__main__':
    lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
```

To get text with number in one line I would print it as single string

```
print(f"Still running: {running.value}\n", end='', flush=True)
```

---

**EDIT:**

As I know `multiprocessing` may works little different on Linux and Windows. Some of them may need variables inside or outside `if __name__ == '__main__':`.

---

```py
import multiprocessing

running = multiprocessing.Value('i', 0)
lock = multiprocessing.Lock()

def f(x):
    global running
    global lock

    # ... code ...
    
    with lock:    
        running.value -= 1
        print(f"Still running: {running.value}\n", end='', flush=True)
   
    return x

if __name__ == '__main__':
    #lock = multiprocessing.Lock()
    
    rangeval = range(100)
    running.value = len(rangeval)
    
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=multiprocessing.cpu_count())
    result = pool.map(f, iterable=rangeval)
```

Result:

```
Still running: 99
Still running: 98
Still running: 97
Still running: 96
Still running: 95
Still running: 94
Still running: 93
Still running: 92
Still running: 91
Still running: 90
Still running: 89
Still running: 88
Still running: 87
Still running: 86
Still running: 85
Still running: 84
Still running: 83
Still running: 82
Still running: 81
Still running: 80
Still running: 79
Still running: 78
Still running: 77
Still running: 76
Still running: 75
Still running: 74
Still running: 73
Still running: 72
Still running: 71
Still running: 70
Still running: 69
Still running: 68
Still running: 67
Still running: 66
Still running: 65
Still running: 64
Still running: 63
Still running: 62
Still running: 61
Still running: 60
Still running: 59
Still running: 58
Still running: 57
Still running: 56
Still running: 55
Still running: 54
Still running: 53
Still running: 52
Still running: 51
Still running: 50
Still running: 49
Still running: 48
Still running: 47
Still running: 46
Still running: 45
Still running: 44
Still running: 43
Still running: 42
Still running: 41
Still running: 40
Still running: 39
Still running: 38
Still running: 37
Still running: 36
Still running: 35
Still running: 34
Still running: 33
Still running: 32
Still running: 31
Still running: 30
Still running: 29
Still running: 28
Still running: 27
Still running: 26
Still running: 25
Still running: 24
Still running: 23
Still running: 22
Still running: 21
Still running: 20
Still running: 19
Still running: 18
Still running: 17
Still running: 16
Still running: 15
Still running: 14
Still running: 13
Still running: 12
Still running: 11
Still running: 10
Still running: 9
Still running: 8
Still running: 7
Still running: 6
Still running: 5
Still running: 4
Still running: 3
Still running: 2
Still running: 1
Still running: 0
```

Comment: I am getting an error ` line 11, in f with lock: NameError: name 'lock' is not defined` but `lock` is defined as global. I am not sure what is going on!

Comment: as I know `multiprocessing` may need some differences on Linux or Windows. It works on Linux but maybe your system needs `lock` outside `if __name__ == '__main__':` like `running`.

Comment: Yeah, I am using windows. I tried putting `lock = multiprocessing.Lock()` outside of `if __name__ == '__main__'` but it outputs some weird numbers that are like `still running: -1 ... -15` and never show 100.

Comment: maybe it will need to set value `running.value = len(rangeval)` also before `if __name__ == '__main__'. OR maybe it will need to send `running` to all functions as argument in `pool.map()` - something like `pool.map(..., args=[running for _ in range(rangeval)]`